# Typhoon build architecture error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, typhoon

**Error :**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TyphoonAssembly", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppAssembly in AppAssembly.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TyphoonBlockComponentFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppAssembly.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TyphoonComponentFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in UIViewController+PropertyInjector.o
      objc-class-ref in ReminderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppAssembly+AddReminder.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppAssembly+Dashboard.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TyphoonDefinition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppAssembly.o
      objc-class-ref in AppAssembly+ViewControllers.o
      objc-class-ref in AppAssembly+Actions.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TyphoonAssembly", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppAssembly in AppAssembly.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What are the build configurations, architecture. I am using 
cocoa pods, XCode 7.1, target iOS version is 8.4. How can I solve this build error?

---

**Podfile**

---

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

xcodeproj 'Proj'


pod 'KGModal'
pod 'JSONKit'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'

target :Proj, :exclusive => true do
    # pod 'Typhoon', :head
end

target :ProjTest, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Kiwi'
end
```

---

**Podfile install output**

---

```
Update all pods    
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Typhoon (3.4.1)
Using Bolts (1.4.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.7.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.7.1)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.7.1)
Using JRSwizzle (1.0)
Using JSONKit (1.4)
Using KGModal (1.2.0)
Using Kiwi (2.4.0)
Using TTTAttributedLabel (1.13.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 8 dependencies from the Podfile and 9
total pods installed.
```

This is pod update output, There is no other errors in terminal and I added $(inherited) to linker search path

Comment: CocoaPods, Typhoon (3.4.1) what is the problem?

Comment: Ohh sorry Objective-C, I searched more and I used "pod 'Typhoon', :head)" at last, but did not successful

Comment: @Subhash Please look ar your OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS, do you have $(inherited) there? Seems that problem is with cocoapods. Could you add your Podfile and "pod install" output to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the updated info. Was your project working fine before adding Typhoon pod? Do you have Typhoon dependency in your Pods project->Build phases->Target Dependencies? http://joxi.ru/Y82QNJnT3pOYAd.jpg

Comment: Alexander thank you for your responses up to now, It does not have any dependencies. Can you save my time any more?

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic error because your Xcode is unable to search for library you want through pod. Try the following steps before installing cocoapods:

1. clean your project
2. remove all the libraries you want to include via Cocoapods.
3. Add **$inherited** in your Linker Search Path in Build Settings.
4. Follow all steps of cocoapods installation as given on Cococapods.org.
5. check for any errors which might come in terminal.
   If any error rectify them , and agin install podfile
6. after installing podfile clean your project again (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>).

Also lastly if you have done all these steps and still showing this error. check whether the libraries you are importing is getting imported via pods or manual. change them to 
`#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` kind.

If still getting error post a comment.